# use variable on left side of object declaration

Tags: javascript, object

Is there any option as I can use a variable on the left side of my object declaration? Something like this:

```
var col = 'col';
var gridDataVK4000 = {
    items : []
};

for (var i = 0; i <= 14; i++) {
    col += col + i;
    // we now push to the item property
    gridDataVK4000.items.push({
        col : i,
    });
}
```

because my example isn't working. :(

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: Whats the reason to do this col increment? I think thats not clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to declare it outside of the curly braces using square bracket notation, otherwise you're assigning the key `"col"`, literally, to your object.

```
var result = {};
result[col] = i;

gridDataVK4000.items.push(result);
```